# SilverStripe display has_one relation values

Tags: php, silverstripe, silverstripe-4

I'm stuck in an misunderstood/logic issue.

I always worked in SilverStripe on cases were was needed to display `has_many` and `many_many` relations data between `DatObjects`, normally managed via field types like `GridField` and so on. But now, I'm stuck in a case where I should display some data from a specific `DataObject` inside another one. They're related via `has_one / belongs_to` relation.
In my example, I have these two objects running on SS 4.0.3:

Object 1 - Subscriber:

```
private static $has_one = [
    'Card' => 'Card'
];
```

Object 2 - Card:

```
private static $db = [
    'Number' => 'Varchar'
];
private static $belongs_to = [
    'Subcriber' => 'Subscriber'
];
```

I would display data from `Card` inside `Subscriber`. Normally, my logic should go in this way: by using the dot notation to declare the related `Card` field (as well as declaring `$summary_fields`, i.e.):

Subscriber - getCMSFields():

```
$fields->addFieldToTab('Root.Main', TextField::create('Card.Number', 'ID Card serial number'));
```

So, at this point I should see the card number loaded in the `TextField`, but data missing. Either if I convert the source parameter in `$this->Card()->Number` the field still empty.

What am I missing?

## Bonus Question

In the case I would invert the logic and, in addition to this, display a `Subscriber` field inside `Card`, I think that this approach can't be possible, right? If I'm right, I should convert `belongs_to` to `has_many` in `Card` in order to achieve this, that's correct?

Thanks for your support.

Comment: Afaik this never worked for Fields, for SS3 there is a module called "HasOneEdit" https://github.com/stevie-mayhew/hasoneedit for this kind of problem. It's currently updated to SS4, I don't know if it's stable enough now. Of course you can set the value of the text field manually and save it in `onAfterWrite()` if that's the only field in your project.

Comment: _Of course you can set the value of the text field manually and save it in onAfterWrite()_. 
This could be the way, thanks @wmk for suggestion. I'll try to this direction, so let's see.